# LINQ To SQL: simpest way to rebuild dbml file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

What is the easiest way to rebuild a dbml file with Visual Studio 2008? There is no "refresh" option in popup menu as in the Entity Framework wizard.

I use bat file (that executes sqlmetal) from the project nowadays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add column to the database - how do i update the dbml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212107/add-column-to-the-database-how-do-i-update-the-dbml-file)